# Sequence is decreasing/increasing for all odd terms $n\in\mathbb{N}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

> Define the sequence $\{a_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ with $a_0=1$ and $a_{n+1}=1+\frac{1}{a_n}$. Show that for all odd terms $n\in\mathbb{N}$:  $a_{n-1}\leq{}a_{n+1}$ and $a_n\geq{}a_{n+2}$.

How do we go about proving this with induction? I realize that the statement holds for $n=1$ such that $1=a_{0}\leq{}a_{2}=\frac{3}{2}$ and $2=a_{1}\geq{}a_{3}=\frac{5}{3}$; this way the basis is verified. But am stuck proving the induction step. Also, does proving this imply that the subsequence made of odd terms is monotonically increasing? What can I say about the subsequence of even terms? Thank you for your time.

Comment: For whoever is down-voting this, you could atleast explain why lol..

Comment: Have you calculated a few terms of the sequence?  Do you know what the limit $L$ is?  Can you show that if $a_n<L$ then $a_{n+1}>L$ and vice versa?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I have calculated a few terms of the sequence and it seems that $a_{2k}$ is increasing while $a_{2k+1}$ is decreasing, they seem to converge to a value approximating 1.6

Comment: The limit is a solution of $x=1+\dfrac1x$

Comment: Have you expressed $a_{n+2}$ in terms of $a_n$? What does this tell you?

Comment: Note:  this sequence is ratios of consecutive Fibonacci numbers

Answer (score 1):

**Hints:**

Note that $a_n>1$ for $n>0$.

The limit of the sequence is $\phi=1.618...$, where $\phi=1+\dfrac1\phi$; i.e., $\phi^2-\phi-1=0$.

If $a_n<\phi$, then $\dfrac1{a_n}>\dfrac1\phi,$ so $a_{n+1}=1+\dfrac1{a_n}>1+\dfrac1\phi=\phi$.

If $a_n>\phi$, then $\dfrac1{a_n}<\dfrac1\phi,$ so $a_{n+1}=1+\dfrac1{a_n}<1+\dfrac1\phi=\phi $.

If $a_n<\phi$, then $a_n^2-a_n-1<0,$ so $a_n^2+a_n<2a_n+1,$ so $\dfrac{a_{n+2}}{a_n}=\dfrac{2a_n+1}{a_n^2+a_n}>1$.

If $a_n>\phi$, then $a_n^2-a_n-1>0,$ so $a_n^2+a_n>2a_n+1,$ so $\dfrac{a_{n+2}}{a_n}=\dfrac{2a_n+1}{a_n^2+a_n}<1$.

The subsequence of terms with odd index  is monotonically *de*creasing.

Answer (score -1):

Use $$a_{n+1}-\frac{\sqrt5+1}{2}=\frac{1}{a_n}-\frac{\sqrt5-1}{2}=\frac{1}{a_n}-\frac{1}{\frac{\sqrt5+1}{2}}=\frac{\frac{\sqrt5+1}{2}-a_n}{\frac{\sqrt5+1}{2}\cdot a_n}$$ and
$$a_{n+1}-a_{n-1}=1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{a_{n-1}}}-a_{n-1}=$$
$$=\frac{1+a_{n-1}-a_{n-1}^2}{a_{n-1}+1}=
\frac{\left(\frac{\sqrt5+1}{2}-a_{n-1}\right)\left(\frac{\sqrt5-1}{2}+a_{n-1}\right)}{a_{n-1}+1}.$$